# Building SQL Query with NULL check

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a stored procedure in SQL Server 2014 and is given below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUsers]
@Role INT
    SELECT FirstName, LastName  
    FROM Users 
    WHERE FirstName = 'Something'
    IF NULLIF(@Role, '') IS NOT NULL    
    BEGIN
        AND Role = @Role
    END
 END
```

With this it is throwing Syntax error at `AND`

I want to build the query dynamically and exclude `NULL` and `''` values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't build a dynamic query like that. But you can use boolean logic

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName  
FROM Users 
Where FirstName = 'Something'
AND (@Role is null or @Role = '' or Role = @Role)
```